# TypeError: undefined is not an object in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a podcast app using react native and PHP/MySQL.

I have stored each podcast and it's details in a MySQL database and am using PHP to get the information with a query.

I then fetch the information in react native and convert it to JSON format.

I am using react-native sound in order to play the podcast within the app.

Here is my code.

```js
 constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.FileUrlHolder = this.FileUrlHolder.bind(this);
      this.state = {
          playState:'paused', //playing, paused
          playSeconds:0,
          duration:0,
          FileUrlHolder: ''

      }

      this.sliderEditing = false;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      fetch('http://da48c35f.ngrok.io/Filter.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

            // Getting the id.
            id: this.props.navigation.state.params.FlatListClickItemHolder
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => { 

        this.setState({ 
            FileUrlHolder: responseJson[0].FileUrl 
        }); 
        //console.log(responseJson[0].FileUrl);

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })


  play = async () => {
      if(this.sound){
          this.sound.play(this.playComplete);
          this.setState({playState:'playing'});
      }else{

        const filepath = this.state.FileUrlHolder;
        console.log('[Play]', filepath);

          this.sound = new Sound(filepath, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
              if (error) {
                  console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
                  Alert.alert('Notice', 'audio file error. (Error code : 1)');
                  this.setState({playState:'paused'});
              }else{
                  this.setState({playState:'playing', duration:this.sound.getDuration()});
                  this.sound.play(this.playComplete);
              }
          });    
      }
  }
```

I am trying to access the state of the Fileurl within the play function so that I can use it to access the correct file to play.

When I run my app I get the following error.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.FileUrlHolder.bind')

How do I fix this?

Comment: where are you calling it from?

Comment: Why do you even need this `this.FileUrlHolder = this.FileUrlHolder.bind(this);`?

Comment: As the error says, `this.FileUrlHolder` is undefined. Note that `Function.prototype.bind` must be called on a function, and in the code you've shared, there is no `FileUrlHolder` function on `this`.

Comment: I understand that now

Comment: When I delete that line then const filepath = this.state.FileUrlHolder; doesn't work –

Comment: Can you `console.log(this);` in your `play()` function and check which object it outputs?

Comment: i thought you had this.FileUrlHolder as a function in the class but ok , bind exists in the proto of Function .

Comment: i did console.log(this); but it didn't print anything

Comment: can you make a small project a prototype on snack ? or any other platform if possible

Comment: I'm new to react native and am unsure as to what you mean

Comment: https://snack.expo.io you can create a small project here as a prototype if you still cant do it i can help you

Answer (score -1):

FileUrlLoader is not property of your component, it is a state  key, thus just remove that binding line

Comment: when I do that const filepath = this.state.FileUrlHolder; doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

you need this.FileUrlHolder = this.FileUrlHolder.bind(this) only if you have function called FileUrlHolder